# Colorbox - linking to an HTML file but parsing a variable via colorbox which changes content of HTML file?

Tags: jquery, colorbox

Sorry - I may not have explained this too well. Basically I'm a designer who is relatively new to jQuery. Our team are working on a project where we require an image (and others grouped by the rel attribute) to load up into a shadowbox. That's fine - I've integrated Colorbox into the page concerned and all works fine.

Now some bright spark has had the idea that we should display 'banner advertising' on the colorbox window underneath the image we have displayed as it will generate revenue for the business.

Now my initial thought is that it could possible be done by using the iframe method as we can call an HTML page which has the banner code on that (I'm yet to work out whether it would reload a new banner advert when the user is navigating through the gallery).

The thing is... our site is sort of like an Autotrader.co.uk if you will - basically the potential for A LOT of images - a user can upload as many as they want, it's not limited - so I really don't want to have to create a new HTML page EVERY time a new image gets uploaded as that's just ridiculous.

Forgive me if this is a stupid question... but is there any way that we can create 1 HTML file (with the banner ad code) on and then parse the image src via colorbox in some way? OR edit the colorbox script so that it has an area for the banner ad at the top of the image?

I've been trying to work out how Autotrader do it and it looks like they have a different URL for each image?

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated...

And just so you can see what we are trying to achieve, click on one of the thumbnails and you'll see the banner ad display above the image

http://www.autotrader.co.uk/classified/advert/201118386320705/sort/priceasc/usedcars/make/abarth/page/1/radius/1500/quicksearch/true/postcode/so152ed?logcode=p

Thanks

Update:

Presently we just have a 'product detail' page - there is a jQuery image gallery and colorbox is used to display the larger images, HTML of that section is below;

---

```
<div id="fragment-1" class="ui-tabs-panel">
              <div class="boatImages">
                <div class="underOfferBanner"></div>
                <a href="http://www.solarnavigator.net/animal_kingdom/animal_images/cat_yawning_canine_teeth.jpg" rel="gallery" title="Angry cat - or is it just yawning?"><img src="http://www.examplesite.com/boatImages/2010/11/2/9521834.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="fragment-2" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
              <div class="boatImages">
                <div class="underOfferBanner"></div>
                <a href="http://files.overyourhead.co.uk/images/misc/Cat%20with%20too%20much%20time.jpg" rel="gallery"><img src="http://www.examplesite.com/boatImages/2010/11/2/9521834.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="fragment-3" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
              <div class="boatImages">
                <div class="underOfferBanner"></div>
                <a href="http://www.solarnavigator.net/animal_kingdom/animal_images/cat_yawning_canine_teeth.jpg" rel="gallery"><img src="http://www.examplesite.com/boatImages/2010/11/2/9521834.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
            </div>
            <div id="fragment-4" class="ui-tabs-panel ui-tabs-hide">
              <div class="boatImages">
                <div class="underOfferBanner"></div>
                <a href="http://files.overyourhead.co.uk/images/misc/Cat%20with%20too%20much%20time.jpg" rel="gallery"><img src="http://www.examplesite.com/boatImages/2010/11/2/9521834.jpg" alt="" /></a></div>
            </div>
```

---

At the moment the images just open in colorbox as normal images

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("a[rel='gallery']").colorbox();       
</script>
```

---

the colorbox script is as per the download on the main site - http://colorpowered.com/colorbox - i did add it but took my post over 3000 character limit.

---

The HTML page would be something along the lines of this

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="bannerAdvertGoesHere">
<!--banner ad script goes here - changes dynamically -->
</div>
<div id="galleryImage">
<!-- need to try and change the url of the image below from the trigger on product detail page -->
<img src="test-image.gif" width="600" height="600" alt="test" /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Ideally we'd like this one HTML page to have the image on it dynamically change depending on what image was clicked on the 'product detail' page.

Failing that - maybe if someone could point me in the right direction of how i could alter the shadowbox code so that the banner script is actually part of it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just to get this straight, you have a banner advert on your page, which is dynamic. And you'd like this exact banner advert to be displayed under an image in a lightbox? Also, could you post up the code you have so far.

Comment: Hi - I've edited the post above with HTML and jQuery. In essence yex, the banner ad needs to display above/beneath (not fussed) the image in the lightbox - however, as mentioned, the colorbox script is also used elsewhere to open up web pages/other links and it's not necessary to have this banner advert display on these.

Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the easiest thing to do would be to create your own markup and pass that to colorbox's html property.  Here is an example:

```
$("a[rel='example1']").colorbox({width:800, height:500, html:function(){
    return "<div><div class='banner' style='width:300px; height:50px; background:#f00;'></div><img src='"+this.href+"'/></div>";
}});
```

With each 'example1' being a link to an photo.  The drawback to doing it this way is that you lose the ability to auto-size (since colorbox isn't going to know what the size of your newly created IMG element is until it loads).

Comment: Ok, this makes sense... although it's not an actual image that i would need to pass, it's google adsense script (which would display images/flash) - would this still work? Trying to dig out the code now...

Comment: Hi - the script code is literally the below... would this work?

<script type='text/javascript'>
GA_googleFillSlot("Live_HeaderBanner");
</script>

Comment: Jack, is there a way to have auto-size in the above case?

Comment: Sure, just leave the width/height properties out.  However, you might want to specify a width otherwise it's going to span the entire screen (as block elements are expected to do).

Comment: I've done something like that and the first time it opens the image it doesn't have the auto-size. Can you suggest a way on how to achieve the autoSize when the image is opened for the first time. Great plugin! `$(".file").colorbox({html:function(){return "<div style='height:auto;'><img style='width:400px;' src='"+this.href+"' border='0'/><div style='text-align:center;;'>"+this.title+"</div></div>";}});`

Comment: Colorbox just sticks your markup into the document and takes the width and height.  Nothing fancy like iterating through it and preloading all of the images.  If you know the height of the image, just set the height in the css or on the elements hight attribute.

Comment: If you don't know the height, then you might have to write your own image loader.  Open an empty colorbox -> load each img element -> open colorbox again with your markup.

Comment: To anyone who might want to use colorbox without knowing the dimensions of the images which will be loaded, here is a workaround that I used. Create `<img style="width: 0;height: 0;padding: 40px 65px 30px 20px;" onmouseover="this.src='http://mydomain.com/BIG_version.jpg';"/>` create the style with padding that matches your clickable area so that you keep the area affected by the onmouse event. Make width/height 0 to hide large img. Then you will be caching your large images when you point on the <a href which uses colorbox. Display:none, visibility:hidden hides the element, so it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how you are calling your banner image.  If it's an image which calls a banner script as its source, you could dynamically inject the image.  For example,

```
$("a[rel='gallery']").colorbox({
    onLoad: function() {
        $("cboxLoadedContent").prepend($("#bannerImg"));
    }
});
```

And in your HTML, you would have the banner image:

```
<p style="display:none;>
    <img src="http://www.domain.com/banner.cgi?Id=123" id="bannerImg"/>
</p>
```

If you can provide an example of your banner script, I can provide more details.

Comment: The banner script is literally just the below - with more google ad script in the head of the page...

<script type='text/javascript'>
GA_googleFillSlot("Live_HeaderBanner");
</script>